# Make ruby program run through each part of array in image download code

Tags: ruby

```
Net::HTTP.start("static.flickr.com") { |http|
  resp = http.get("/92/218926700_ecedc5fef7_o.jpg")
  open("fun.jpg", "wb") { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
   }
}
```

Theres some sample image download code. Now, instead of having it open, i want to save it to an already chosen directory. Also, i would like it to run through each URL in an array. Using 4chan as an example (I'm making an image ripper.) Heres what the array contains, after ripping them from the source code:

```
http://static.4chan.org/image/title/1065156729813.jpg
http://static.4chan.org/support/jlist_leader/728x90_gothic.jpg
http:flag.jpg
http://static.4chan.org/support/jlist_top/jlist_adult_01.jpg
http://images.4chan.org/v/src/1296062231626.png
```

(etc)
So heres what i propose to do:
URI parse each URL through the array somehow
Enter each portion of each parsed URL into each of the spots sequentially
If the image cannot be downloaded / parsed (for example, matches like flag.jpg), it skips it
It saves them all into a predefined directory, without opening them. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you know what you want to do, so what, specifically, are you having trouble coding?

Comment: Making the downloader run through each parsed object from the array.

Comment: Also, getting it to saved a downloaded object into a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by organizing each URL by host, then you iterating over each host and image, downloading as you go.  Something like this:

```
require 'uri'

# Organize URLs by host.
by_host = {}
urls.each do |x| # Assume 'urls' is an Array of String URLs.
  begin
    uri = URI.parse(x)
    by_host[uri.host] = [] unless by_host[uri.host]
    by_host[uri.host] << uri
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    STDERR.puts "Invalid URL: #{x}"
  end
end

# Now download each image from each host.
by_host.each do |host, uris|
  Net::HTTP.start(host) do |http|
    uris.each do |uri|
      resp = http.get(uri.path)
        File.open(uri.path, "wb") {|file| file.write(resp.body)}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you'll need more error checking and you'll probably want to organize by host/port instead of just hostname, but the above example should demonstrate the idea, in general, especially the use of the [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/Generic.html) class in Ruby.

As for saving into directories, you'll want to either ensure that the full path to each `uri.path` exists or create it before trying to open the output file.

Comment: I take it to save it to the final directory I need to modify that last line there. If I was to use File.open("C:\\", "wb"){|file| file.write(resp.body)} would it save to C:\?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll figure it out on my own. Thanks for the help man.